# Computing whether a particular finitely presented group is infinite with GAP

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, gap, infinite-groups

I am working with GAP 4 and trying to check whether a finitely presented group is infinite.
Since the `Size`-function dies on me I followed the suggestion in the GAP manual to try working with the low index subgroups.
Based on https://www.gap-system.org/Doc/Examples/cavicchioli.html I came up with the following code:

```
F:=FreeGroup(["f1", "f2", "t1", "t2", "t3"]);
AssignGeneratorVariables(F);
T:=F/[f1^2,f2^2,t1^3,t3^3,(t2)^5,(t1*f1)^2,t3^-1*f1*t2,f2*t2^-1*t1^-1];

maxIndex:=30;
u := LowIndexSubgroupsFpGroup(T,TrivialSubgroup(T),maxIndex);
u := Filtered(u,i->Index(T,i)>1);
Collected(List(u,i->IsInfiniteAbelianizationGroup(i)));
```

Which gives me the result: `[ [ true, 1 ], [ false, 30 ] ]`

Can this be counted as a proof that the finitely presented group above is infinite?

This question is related to [Finding low-index normal subgroups of finitely presented groups in GAP](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3697546/finding-low-index-normal-subgroups-of-finitely-presented-groups-in-gap).

Comment: I've edited the title. You're looking at a particular presentation, right? Because the question is undecidable in general; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3106606/104041).

Comment: I think you'll find that during the execution of your last line of code, GAP automatically sets the `Size` and `IsFinite` properties of your group $T$.

Comment: Yes, it is a proof (and one of the standard ways to prove infinity).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I believe so.

If the abelianisation $G^{{\rm ab}}$ of a group $G$ is infinite, so is $G$. If a subgroup $G$ of a group $H$ is infinite, so is $H$.

I don't see any obvious mistakes in your programme.